# Problems Installing React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with react and I try to install it, I followed the following steps :
1) curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
2) sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
3) sudo npm install npm@latest -g
4) npm install -g create-react-app
5) create-react-app awesome-project

at the step 5 I got stuck with this error.
What shoudl I do?
thank you in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWwWM.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install npm package || permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181159/unable-to-install-npm-package-permission-denied)

Comment: Have you tried running all the commands with sudo?

Comment: What version are you using? Because in your explanation you downloaded the script and execute bash from stdin and then you ran sudo apt-get install -y nodejs. If you can tell us the version would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `npm install -g create-react-app`, use `sudo npm install -g create-react-app`.